# Why I can't implement this simple CSS

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Enjoy BluePrint</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
        <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->

        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> -->
        <script type="text/css">
            h1.logo {
                        width:181px; height:181px;
                        background: url("img/logo.png");
                        text-indent: -9999px;
                    } 
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header" class="span-24">
                <div id="logo" class="span-6">
                    <h1 class="logo">This is my site</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="script" class="span-10">
                   <p>Frank Chimero is a graphic designer, illustrator, teac`her, maker, writer,  thinker-at-large in Portland, Oregon.</p> 
                </div>
                <div id="contact" class="span-8 last">
                    contact
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Content -->
            <div id="main-content" class="span-12">
                <h3>DISCOVERY</h3>
                <p>My fascination with the creative process, curiosity, and visual experience informs all of my work in some way. Each piece is the part of an exploration in finding wit, surprise, honesty, and joy in the world around us, then, trying to document those things with all deliberate speed before they vanish.</p><br/>
                <p>Our creative output can have a myriad intended outcomes: to inform, to persuade or sell, or delight. There are many other creative people who do well in servicing the needs to inform or persuade, but there are not many out there who have taken up the mantle of delighting people. I’ll try my best.</p><br/>
                <p>It’s not about pretty; it is about beauty. Beauty in form, sure, but also beauty in the fit of a bespoke idea that transcends not only the tasks outlined, but also fulfilling the objectives that caused the work to be produced in the first place.</p><br/>
                <p>The best creative work connects us by speaking to what we share. From that, we hope to make things that will last. Work made without staying power and lasting relevance leads to audiences that are fickle, strung along on a diet of crumbs.</p><br/>
                <p>The work should be nourishing in some way, both while a creative person is making it, but also while someone consumes it. When I think of all my favorite books, movies, art and albums, they all make me a little less alone and a little more sentient. Perhaps that is what making is for: to document the things that make us feel most alive.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- Side -->
            <div id="award" class="span-4">
                Awards
            </div>
            <div id="right-sidebar" class="span-8 last">
                Right sidebar
            </div>

        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm 100% sure the code works, and I can't replace image at h1.logo . I try to use live-editing CSS tool and it works fine .

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 11):

its not script its style.

```
<style type="text/css">
     h1.logo {
         width:181px; height:181px;
         background: url("img/logo.png");
         text-indent: -9999px;
     } 
</style>
```